# Developing a RoR application with "levels" of difficulty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, dry

I'm building a RoR application with varying levels of "difficulty." The site is intentionally designed to be hackable, to teach students how to better secure their web applications.

At each increasing level of difficulty, sanitization/security checks will be slightly more advanced. As an example for SQL injection:

- Beginner - simply insert `'` and you break out into the RAW sql
- Intermediate - inserting `'` breaks into RAW sql, but certain keywords (like DROP, ALTER, etc) are "blocked"...
- Advanced - username & password are fully sanitized but vulnerable to attacks from a different charset, etc...

What's the best way to code this in a DRY manner? Right now, I'm using a (terrible) pattern like:

```
if level == 1
  # code for beginner
elsif level == 2
  # code for intermediate
else
  # code for advanced
end
```

This happens multiple times :(. What's the best way to implement this kind of pattern?

Comment: Seth, is your question how to refactor the if/else block, or how to redesign the entire program to not need it? Are you specifically worried about your models, controllers, or views -- or all of the above? It's hard to suggest a refactoring based on the information you've provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a good place to use monkeypatching, using modules inside lib/.

Say you want a `Client` resource. You start by putting the "common" (shared by all dificulty levels) functionality on the default files (Alternatively, you can put the "easy" implementation there)

```
# /app/models/client.rb
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  def foo
    # default and/or "easy" implementation
  end
end

# /app/controllers/client_controller.rb
class ClientController < ApplicationController
  def bar
    # default and/or "easy" implementation
  end
end
```

Monkeypatches for `client.rb` and `client_controller.rb` on the 'medium' difficulty could be placed inside the `/lib/medium` module :

```
# /lib/medium/models/client_patch.rb
class Client
  def foo
    # medium implementation
  end
end

# /lib/medium/controllers/client_controller_patch.rb
class ClientController
  def bar
    # medium implementation
  end
end
```

You will need a file that includes all those patches depending on the difficulty. A simple solution would be a simple file like this:

```
# /lib/medium.rb
require 'medium/models/client_patch'
...
require 'medium/controllers/client_controller_patch'
```

So you can require it from an initializer:

```
# /config/initializers/difficulty.rb

# require 'easy'
require 'medium'
# require 'difficult'
```

You can then launch three different instances of the application, one on easy, one on medium and one on difficult. The code will be shared, with the exception of the difficulty.rb initializer (and I'll assume that you will also need different configuration files for the database, log files etc).

Comment: From this it sounds like the whole thing could be taken care of more simply with environments.

Comment: @Eric: I thought about using environments, but I realized that I'd need an initializer in any case. Ultimately I didn't see any advantages in coupling the difficulty with the environments.

Comment: By my reading I think it's simpler to start the app up with a specific environment than to (un-) comment the difficulty.rb initializer. No chance of typos.

Comment: The cost is that you have to have several environment files inside /config/environments, each with 5 or 6 LOC. And duplicate those if you have production and staging environments. And the web server (Apache or whatever) config files have to take that into account. With the initializer-only, you set the initializer just like you would set database.yml, and you are good to go. No additional files inside /config/environments, and simpler web server options. But yeah, it is a personal preference.

Answer (score 1):

use a helper function or assign some levels to your students.

Student will have a level and in your application controller, you have a

```
def level_of(student)
```

or something. OR you could use some sort of authentication protocol where certain users can only access some modules/controllers/whatnot:

https://github.com/stffn/declarative_authorization or https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

in declarative auth you can put this in your config/authorization_rules.rb:

```
authorization do

  role :beginner do
    has_permission_on [:simple_inserts], :to => :manage
  end

  role :intermediate do
    has_permission_on [:simple_inserts], :to => :manage
  end 
end
```

etc etc.

All you have to do is to tell our controllers that it's using declarative auth and it will do the rest.

Comment: this doesn't answer the question. i know how to assign roles to students. i want to know if there's a better patterning other than repeated if/elsif/else/end to execute various levels... the user actually has a dropdown to choose what level they want

Comment: declarative auth can do that for you in. you just need to declare the levels and permissions on your init file and let it do the rest(no need to repeated if elses in views controllers etc)

Comment: i don't think you're understanding the question. the user is not tied to a level. a user has no permissions. the level determines how vulnerable code is, that's it

Answer (score 0):

Run 3 rails applications, either on the same server or on multiple... This way, succeeding the 'hack' at level 1 won't crash the sites for level 2 or 3

Comment: It's sandboxed... and they use the same layout, etc. I'd rather repeat the above pattern than have 3 separate layouts and codebases to deal with